# AWS ALB Client TLS Negotiation Error Occurring on the Hour or Half Hour

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scala, tls1.2, timeoutexception

I have a Scala application managed by ecs that makes a call through an alb to various python applications also managed by ecs. This application sends a significant amount of traffic through the alb (on the order of 750 requests/min). The problem is That I am on occasionally getting a `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`. This error seems to occur when there are 5+ Client TLS Negotiation Errors occurring through the alb. These Client TLS Negotiation Errors are occurring on the hour or half hour in random intervals. For Example: the error could occur at 4:30, 8:00, 12:00, 15:30, 18:00 on a particular day. Unfortunately the python applications are black boxes to me and I don't have access to the logs. My question is what could be causing these tls issues? Also could I discount the python applications as being part of the issue? I am using a legitimate ssl cert, but I am also using `.option(HttpOptions.allowUnsafeSSL)` when performing the rest calls.

Comment: It seems that your application is too busy doing the work it does and thus some requests are timing out.

Comment: @sarveshseri If it were too busy at times what do you think explains the time interval trend. I am seeing these tls errors primarily occurring on an even hour or half hour. e.g 1:30, 4:00, 12:00, 17:30, 20:00.

Comment: keyword being "primarily". Since its a simple "Read Time Out" at socket level, it should have 'nothing to with TLS or anything else.